# Why isn't "Enterprise" spelt "Enterprize" in US English?

Tags: orthography

I live in Australia, but am expected to use US English in my work. I am therefore used to spelling "-ise" as "-ize". I was a little surprised to find that "enterprise" is almost universally spelt with "-ise". *Is there any particular reason that this is the case for this example*, when "-ize" is so widely preferred in US English?

Comment: I surmise you’re just improvising here without actual knowledge. I despise it when people are surprised that there is actually an undisguised method and reason behind these things; consider yourself duly apprised that there very much is such. And while I don’t quite mean to chastise you ***too*** severely, I must advise you to study English morphology with considerably more diligence than heretofore displayed that you might excise these ridiculous notions from your head. This may, however, require that a tutor supervise your exercises.

Comment: @tchrist - Pompous much?

Comment: @ErikKowal *woosh*.

Comment: @ErikKowal ~ tchrist is just playing with words... look at all the -ise words he uses.

Comment: What am I — Eisenstein? :)

Comment: @tchrist That was beautiful. Thank you. You should have posted it as an answer, though, because it definitely deserves rep.

Comment: It still comes off as a little pompous, @LessPop_MoreFizz Such effort would have been better directed toward an answer with an explanation.

Comment: You can probably blame Noah Webster.

Comment: Besides, that's the way the spell it in Star Trek.

Comment: @tchrist _`surmise`_ - I see what you did there... :)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

For one, because the etymology is different.

*-ise* (*-ize*) is a causative suffix in *formalise*, *realise* etc. (to make something formal, to make something real...)

But *enterprise* is not "to make something enterpre" or similar (whatever that might mean). The *prise* bit comes as a past participle of French *prendre* (to grasp, to take).

Another answer is that *enterprize* is actually attested, and was apparently used more than *enterprise* in the second half of 18th century ([N-gram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=enterprize%2C+enterprise&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15)).

Comment: "Enterprise" and "surprise" both come from the French verb "prendre" -- to take. Several of the verb forms of this verb have the "pris" syllable. No surprise (or pun intended) that this is an "-ise" spelling in American and other forms of english.

Comment: Note that "prise" is also an English verb (from the same origin) meaning "to force open".

Comment: Interesting... I always assumed it was related to prix (price)

Comment: That would be "prize", which is a different word altogether.

Comment: @Max in US and Canada (since this is a question about US English), we say "pry" rather than "prise" (past-tense: pried).

Comment: @TylerH: To me, pry and prise are different words. Are you sure prise is not US English, rather than just rare?

Comment: The Oxford Dictionary of English (in OS X's Dictionary app) says the US spelling is "prize", not "pry".

Comment: @Max "prized" is not used in US English to mean "forced open". At least, I have never heard it used as such. Other dictionaries list "pry" as the US English version of the British English "prised"